# How to set up S3 Policies for multiple IAM users such that each individual only has access to their personal bucket folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have two users User1 and User2 that each have an IAM account in AWS. I have an s3 bucket "external_bucket.frommycompany.com". In that bucket is a folder for each user account "User1" and "User2". I want to grant R/W access to User1 to the User1 folder only and R/W access to User2 to the User2 folder only. I don't want them to be able to see each others' folders in the root directory of external_bucket.frommycompany.com. Is there a way to set up their IAM Policies such that this is possible?

My goal is to enable our users to connect to the S3 bucket from an S3 browser app like cloudberry so they can upload and download files to their folders only.

Any advice on the best design for this is welcome.

Comment: For exactly the same case we used to use AD Bridge that work with Drive http://www.cloudberrylab.com/ad-bridge.aspx It allows you to have 1 common folder for users to exchange data and 1 personal folder for each user. And they will not see other user's folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke)

Something like this should work to allow User1 to only access User1's folder:

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
  {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["user1/*"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::user1/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

Apply that as User1's policy, and they should only be able to access the `user1/` folder. The `"s3:prefix":["","/"]...` part can probably be changed, but I'm not familiar enough with the policy language to know how.

If you substitute user2 for user1 in User2's policy, User2 should only be able to access the `user2/` folder, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This is close to what I need, but it is not entirely the solution. I need to prevent the ability for User1 to see the other buckets that exist and the other folders in the individual bucket i have granted him access to. Any ideas how I can change this policy file to enable that?

Comment: You can take out the `AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole` statement to prevent listing of other buckets, and the `AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket` statement to prevent listing of other folders.

Comment: Millinon, This solved my problem. Big thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

This is the [official answer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1) to your question.

> Example: Allow each IAM user access to a folder in a bucket
>
> In this example, you want two IAM users, Alice and Bob, to have access
>   to your bucket, examplebucket, so they can add, update, and delete
>   objects. However, you want to restrict each user’s access to a single
>   folder in the bucket. You might create folders with names that match
>   the user names.

Comment: "you can write a single policy that uses a **policy variable** and attach the policy to a group" Mind blown. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

The use of [policy variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse) is really a game changer if you aren't doing this today.

See this example in [S3 policy examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1):

> Instead of attaching policies to individual users, though, you can
>   write a single policy that uses a policy variable and attach the
>   policy to a group. You will first need to create a group and add both
>   Alice and Bob to the group. The following example policy allows a set
>   of Amazon S3 permissions in the `examplebucket/${aws:username}` folder.
>   When the policy is evaluated, the policy variable `${aws:username}` is
>   replaced by the requester's user name. For example, if Alice sends a
>   request to put an object, the operation is allowed only if Alice is
>   uploading the object to the `examplebucket/Alice` folder.
>
> ```
> {
>    "Version":"2012-10-17",
>    "Statement":[
>       {
>          "Effect":"Allow",
>          "Action":[
>             "s3:PutObject",
>             "s3:GetObject",
>             "s3:GetObjectVersion",
>             "s3:DeleteObject",
>             "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
>          ],
>          "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/${aws:username}/*"
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Great example! This simplifies folder support 100 fold for me.